# What to test: JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I`m starting to work with TypeScript and when I was coding in pure JS, I used to test it with Jest. Now, when I need to test my TS code, I found out that there is ts-jest, but the question is: do I really need it? Because my TS code is compiled into corresponding JS and after this I can test it with normal Jest. So, for what purpose I need to use ts-jest? Or maybe I don't need it?

Comment: ts-jest adds sourcemap support according to their documentation. You get a better debugging experience. Personally, the projects I worked on with typescript were small so I didn't feel a need for it

Comment: A ts-jest workflow lets you write the _tests_ in TypeScript, too.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Do you want to write your tests in TypeScript or don't you? If so, ts-jest will compile your TS code and run your tests so you can debug the TypeScript, not the emitted JS.

Comment: You can do either, if it's a hobby project, doesn't really matter, your preference. If it's a professional environment (you are working with other people), stick to one. I'd find it extremely frustrating switching between languages and various fidelity of IDE support when I write app code vs tests.

Answer (score 3):

From briefly reading the docs, it seems the only difference really is that `ts-jest` transpiles and begins the test suites in one go, so you dont have to transpile it manually before testing. It also type checks it, but it just uses TypeScript itself for that, so I would say it's optional really.